# Resizable ImageButton or Button in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I'm creating a responsive site in C#.NET. I'm able to resize the images, text inside a `div`. But if i try to insert a image button or a button in that resizable div, it doesn't resize. My code is a follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Startscreen.aspx.vb" Inherits="Startscreen" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>::: Eastvalley :::</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/font-resize.js"></script>
    <link href="ProgramStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
        body
        {
            padding-top: 10%;
            padding-bottom: 25%;
        }
        #resizable
        {
            max-width: 662px;
            height: 50px;
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function fontResize() {
            //Set default resolution and font size
            var resolution = 1024;
            var font = 20;

            //Get window width
            var width = $(window).width();

            //Set new font size
            var newFont = font * (width / resolution);
            $('body').css('font-size', newFont);
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            fontResize();
            $(window).bind('resize', function () {
                fontResize();
            });
        }
        );

        $(function () {
            $("#resizable").resizable();
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div id="resizable">
        <table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="TableBorder"
            style="background-color: #91e2ed">
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <img src="images/InnerPageLogo.png" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Welcome to EastValley Water District
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblLangugeSelection" runat="server" Text="Please select your language"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                            <div id="resizable">
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEnglish" ImageUrl="~/images/english.jpg" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" /></div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="right" valign="middle">
                                            <div id="resizable">
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSpanish" ImageUrl="~/images/Spanish.png" runat="server" /></div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The two image buttons that i have used are not resizing. Its looks like this:

Before Re sizing browser:

[image]

After Re sizing browser:

[image]

Please help. I need to create an `image button` or a `button` that dynamically changes size, on browser resize.

Comment: Where in the resize function do you try to resize the buttons? I can only see you trying to resize the font-size. If you want to resize the buttons, you would probably need resize the images the buttons use as background.

Comment: @Bump I'm placing the buttons in re sizable div. But that is not helping. Can u help me with the function to re size button. I didn't find any on web.

Comment: I would create different images of various sizes and then depending on the width of the window use jQuery to set the 'src' attribute to point to a smaller image, for instance. Can you try that? This jQuery function you can use to set an attribute: http://api.jquery.com/attr/. If the asp.net image button doesn't generate proper html you can always use an html input or button tag with an image as background.

Answer (score 0):

First, it appears that it is not possible to make an .net imageButton responsive because the images are all developed server side.  Only HTML img elements are responsive.  One solution is shown in this example.

We create an img tag in the backend code with the image web address and in effect replace the "Label" element with html code generated in the backend code. Since the img tag width must be 100% we set a max-width in the div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title>Demo Responsive Image with asp.net</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <style>
        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div  style="max-width: 500px;">
            <button id="button1" type="button" 
                onclick="window.location.href='https://www.w3schools.com/'">
            <asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" /></button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Backend code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class ResponsiveImage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 Label imageLabel = (Label)FindControl("myLabel");
 imageLabel.Text = @"<img id='thisphoto' src='somephotoUrl'";
}
}
```